# copy position keyframes across time?

Tags: physics, keyframes, timeline

Is there an *elegant* way to copy location/rotation date from one object at some frame to a different object at a different frame? Right now, my best idea is to play a lot with "Apply visual transform" and copy-pasting numbers

More precisely, my plan is as follows: First I render a rigid body animation of 250 frames, say, with a single object A.

Then I want to add an object B and make its location and rotation at frame 1 / frame 2 equal that at frame 251 / frame 252 of object A from the previous run (and afterwards, B follows physics). So B has the initial state of "future" A. Perhaps you can imagine that, if I later append the second movie clip to the first, object B looks like the continuation of object A and the second object A looks like s second object starting with a 250 frame delay.

Preferably, I'd like to repeat, i.e., make a third run with a third object C where C takes the data from future B and B again from future A (perhaps different values this time as B might have collided with A in the second run). And so on as I see fit.

[image]

---

I am aware that I could perhaps achieve the same by running an n times 250 simulation right away, with new objects "starting" every 250 frames. I would still like to explore the idea outlined above because it feels like I could influence the new objects better.

Comment: It's not hard to copy location/rotation data over, but that won't carry velocity information over, so what you'll get is B and C falling to the ground unless you edit their initial velocity.

Comment: @JosephBrandenburg Wouldn't copying the position of two frames before switching from animated to physics solve the velocity problem?

Comment: Yeah, that should work but you'll have to sort of feather the simulations to account for this.